# Changing src of only hovered ng-include element, where value of src is a $scope variable

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have multiple `ng-include` elements that have src attribute set to `$scope.template_url`.

I want to change src of **hovered element only** to new template but changing it's value will change all of elements. How can i implement it?

Html code:

```
<section class="parent">
   <div data-ng-include data-src="template_url"></div>
</section>
```

Javascript (in controller):

```
angular.element(document).on('mouseover', '.parent', function(){
  $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.template_url = "path/to/new/template.html";
  });
});
```

Writing jQuery dom manipulation is dirty and also don't works:

```
$(this).attr('data-src', "path/to/new/template.html");
```

Comment: Could you expand on why you're doing this? It would be good to know how many ng-include statements you expect to have and whether the number of ng-includes will change.

Comment: number of ng-include elements are infinite. they will load by scroll infinite loading. they are banner and by hovering will be converted to slider. i use these method to prevent loading all slider images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making this a directive. Directives have their own scope, so you can still do the "on hover use a different template" idea, but for each individual one that is hovered.

```
<div>
    <div data-some-directive=""></div>
</div>
```

---

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('someDirective', function() {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.model = "Hello"
            $scope.mouseover = function () {
                $scope.model = "Hovered!";
            };
        },
        scope:{},
        restrict: 'AE',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input ng-mouseover="mouseover()" ng-model="model"></div>',
    };
});
```

[Heres a fiddle to see it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/NFALB/1/)

Tweak the template variable in the directive to use a variable on your model for the include url.

By the way, angular already has a mouseover handler, so i've just linked that into the controller with `ng-mouseover` in the template.